# Mongoid and has_secure_password

Tags: authentication, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to use rails 3.1 authentication using mongoid instead of active model

```
 class User 
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  has_secure_password  
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  attr_accessor :email, :password, :password_confirmation 
  field :email, :type => String
  field :password_digest, :type => String
 end
```

the problem is password_digest is not recognized by the bycrypt as in active model example http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put

```
has_secure_password
```

After

```
field :password_digest, :type => String
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer. You need to include ActiveModel::SecurePassword as Adam points out below.

Comment: The original question already contains that. You also need to order things right.

Comment: what if I want to use password only instead of password digest?

Answer (score 40):

For anyone who is interested, the most minimal requirement for using `has_secure_password` with Mongoid is simply the inclusion of `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` in the model.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  field :username
  field :password_digest

  has_secure_password
end
```

[Article](http://z.calepin.co/rails-31s-has_secure_password-with-monogid.html)

Comment: perfect answer.

Comment: Hi, link to article is broken (`404`)