# Rails 3.1 Mongoid has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I'm attempting to get has_secure_password to play nice with mongoid. I'm following Railscasts #270, however when I to signin with a username/password, I get the error:

```
undefined method `find_by_email' for User:Class
```

I see a similar post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920875/mongoid-and-has-secure-password) however, having done as it suggested I still get the same error.

Here is my model:

```
class User 
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword 

  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation

  field :email, :type => String
  field :password_digest, :type => String
  has_secure_password
 end
```

Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end

end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option 1: In your controller, you should use

```
user = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first
```

Option 2: In your model, you should define

```
def self.find_by_email(email)
  where(:email => email).first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid doesn't support the `find_by_attribute` methods.

You should better use `where` instead:

```
User.where(:email => email).all
```